# A list of conjugacy classes in elementary abelian $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, p-groups

> Let $G$ be an elementary abelian $p$-group, how can I get a complete list of conjugacy classes in $G$? A general structure of the conjugacy classes will do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Conjugacy classes in an **abelian** group? Please, just take a minute to think about that concept.

Answer (score 1):

Since $G$ is abelian, for any $g, h\in G$, we have $gh=hg$; in particular, $g=hgh^{-1}$, which means . . .